# How do I create an ADT virtual machine of a specific size that still has the hardware control buttons?

Tags: java, android, virtual-machine, adt

I'm trying to develop a very specific app for my Dell Streak. I want the entire app to run landscape. The Streak has a tilt function that switches the whole OS to a landscape 800x480.

So I want to make an ADT to test in that uses an 800x480 display, but whenever I set the size I get no buttons. The Streak has a Home, Menu and Back button aswell as volume/mute and power, and I need to use some of them for my application.

P.S. I'm not worried about the tilting messing up my application. Not yet, anyway. Just need the test environment the right size and with buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you use non-standard (your own) resolution and there's no skin for that. You should provide your own skin in such a case.

But you don't really have to do that. If you want to have 800x480 you can use `WVGA800`  built-in skin when creating AVD (which is 480x800) and then use `KEYPAD_7` or `Ctrl-F11` and `KEYPAD_9` or `Ctrl-F12` to switch it's orientation to landscape. Then you get 800x480 with full keypad.

-

Besides you can always use keyboard of your PC or laptop to emulate emulator keys:

Home - HOME

Menu - F2 or Page-up

Back - ESC

Power Button - F7

Audio volume up button - KEYPAD_PLUS, Ctrl-F5

Audio volume down button - KEYPAD_MINUS, Ctrl-F6

-

for more see: [Keyboard mapping](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#controlling)